# interact.js I want the dot to stop at the last element

Tags: html, css

The dotted line follows well in the corresponding area.

[image]

If you select another element and move it, the dotted line is not moving along the last element.

[image]

I want the dot to stop at the last element

Any reference point you select will be stretched, and you will need to have a dotted line on it.

```js
// global
let maxWidth = 200;
let maxHeight = 200;
let minWidth = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;

let recentTarget = 0;
let minRecentTarget = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;

var targetWrapper = document.querySelector(".check-box");

import interact from 'https://cdn.interactjs.io/v1.10.11/interactjs/index.js'


// target elements with the "draggable" class
interact('.draggable')
  .draggable({
    // enable inertial throwing
    inertia: false,
    // keep the element within the area of it's parent
    modifiers: [
      interact.modifiers.restrictRect({
        // restriction: '.check-group-wrap',
        // endOnly: true
      })
    ],
    // enable autoScroll
    autoScroll: true,

    listeners: {
      // call this function on every dragmove event
      move: dragMoveListener,

      // call this function on every dragend event
      end: {},
    }
  })

function dragMoveListener(event) {

  var target = event.target;

  // keep the dragged position in the data-x/data-y attributes
  var x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx
  var y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy

  // 최대값 가진 target 찾기
  if (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) + 200 > minRecentTarget && parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) + 200 < recentTarget) {
    minusRecent(x, y);
  } else if (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) + 200 == maxWidth) {
    minusWidth(x, y);
  } else if (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) + 200 < minWidth && parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) + 200 > recentTarget) {
    recentTarget = x + 200;
    minRecentTarget = recentTarget - 5;
  }

  // translate the element
  target.style.transform = 'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)'

  // update the posiion attributes
  target.setAttribute('data-x', x)
  target.setAttribute('data-y', y)

  // update the width, height wrapper
  resetPos(x, y);



}

function resetPos(x, y) {

  if ((x + 200) > maxWidth) {
    maxWidth = x + 200;
  }

  console.log(maxWidth + ',' + minWidth + ',' + recentTarget + ',' + minRecentTarget);

}

// target 이 최대값 타겟일 때
function minusWidth(x, y) {
  maxWidth = x + 200;
  minWidth = maxWidth - 1;
  targetWrapper.style.width = (x + 200) + 'px';
  console.log("최댓값 target");
}

function minusRecent(x, y) {
  recentTarget = x + 200;
  minRecentTarget = recentTarget - 100;
  console.log("최솟값을 가진 target");
}
```

```css
.check-group-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 10%;
}

.check-group {
  position: relative;
}

.check-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9px;
  left: -9px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  clear: both;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px dashed #000;
  padding: 5px;
}

.check {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="check-group-wrap">
  <div class="check-group">
    <div class="check-box"></div>
    <div class="check draggable"></div>
    <div class="check draggable"></div>
    <div class="check draggable"></div>
    <div class="check draggable"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to make a [mcve], but your use import instead of just using it as a script tag

Comment: I didn't understand the question.

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] somwhere, like jsfiddle? The sandbox here does not allow the iframes interact.js creates